# Существует ли библиотека Python, которая делит число столбиком и выводит историю деления?

Tags: python

Допустим, вводим 123/5. Тогда на выходе получим:

```
123|5
10 |24
 23
  3
```

Написал код под первые две строки, а дальше не понимаю как отступы отмерять и складывать разные разряды (ведь надо, чтобы все работало с любыми числами). Вот и спрашиваю, что может быть есть какая-то библиотека, которая это делает?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос. Мы его поправим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
def division(numerator, divisor):
    numerator = str(numerator)
    M = len(numerator)
    divisor = int(divisor)
    res = numerator + ' | ' + str(divisor) + '\n'
    if int(numerator) < int(divisor):
        return res + '0' + ' '*M + '| 0'
    div_res = ''
    i = 0
    while True:
        num = 0
        idx = 0
        while num < divisor:
            idx += 1
            num = int(numerator[:idx])
            if idx > len(numerator):
                res = res.split('\n')
                res[1] += ' '*(M-len(res[1])+1) + '| ' + div_res                
                return '\n'.join(res)
        
        d, m = divmod(num, divisor)
        div_res += str(d)
        if m == 0:
            div_res += '0'
        deduct = divisor*d
        num_ = str(num-deduct)
        if num_ == '0':
            num_ = ''
        numerator = num_  + numerator[idx:]
        res += ' '*i + str(deduct) + '\n' + ' '*((i+1) if num_ !='' else (M-1)) + numerator + '\n'
        i += 1
```

Comment: Не делит (123, 6)

Comment: @MBo, исправил.

Comment: Теперь на 5 не делит ;(

Comment: почему-то не работает с (12345,25)

Comment: @kfcgenius а теперь ?

Comment: @MBo теперь вроде работает ;)

Comment: теперь работает, но не работает с (1234,1423)

Comment: @kfcgenius. проверяйте.

Comment: division(83532,3) в момент ошибки частное уже 6 знаков

Comment: почему-то в (12345,25) в 3 строке ошибка - лишняя пятерка

Answer (score 2):

Если вы в настроении симулировать деление столбиком, то вот этот ответ. "Симулировать" потому что на деле деление делается в машинной арифметике, после чего восстанавливается запись деления столбиком.

Метод `lines` порождает числа которые последовательно вычитаются из делимого, как в обычном делении в столбик. Числа правильно выравнены по правому краю. Нули пропускаются. Последним печатается остаток от деления.

```
def show_division(n, m):
    assert n >= 0
    assert m > 0
    ns = str(n)
    print('{}|{}'.format(ns, m))
    digits = str(n // m)

    def lines():
        for i, d in enumerate(digits):
            if d != '0':
                yield '{}{}'.format(str(int(d) * m), ' ' * (len(digits) - i - 1))
        yield str(n % m)

    for i, line in enumerate(lines()):
        line = line.rjust(len(ns))
        if i == 0:
            print('{}|{}'.format(line, digits))
        else:
            print(line)
    print()


show_division(123, 5)
show_division(123, 6)
show_division(12345, 25)
show_division(1234, 1423)
show_division(83532, 3)
```

> ```
> $ python school_division_simulation.py 
> 123|5
> 10 |24
>  20
>   3
>
> 123|6
> 12 |20
>   3
>
> 12345|25
> 100  |493
>  225 
>    75
>    20
>
> 1234|1423
> 1234|0
>
> 83532|3
> 6    |27844
> 21   
>  24  
>   12 
>    12
>     0
> ```

Comment: А можете объяснить, что метод lines делает?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Ещё раз напомню что это именно симуляция. Честная реализация деления столбиком куда сложнее.